# Why did Lee Abbott say, "I didn't say anything"?

Tags: a-quiet-place

Lee Abbott signs Evelyn Abbott that her face is beautiful:

> Lee Abbott: Beautiful.
>
> *(Evelyn Abbott makes funny expression)*
>
> Lee Abbott: **I didn't say anything**.

Why did he say, "I didn't say anything"?

Comment: Could someone please add a sign-language tag? It seems appropriate to put on this thread in my opinion.

Comment: @AbrahamRay - Hmmm, that seems reasonable. Do we have other language tags?

Comment: @Adamant this sites got a couple of language tags, but I can only remember the Klingon language tag right now.

Comment: When we get a klingon-sign-language tag you know we have gone too far.

Comment: True @DJClayworth however a straight forward sign language tag would be reasonable in my opinion.